# How to randomly spawn objects in plane dimensions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I saw this code in unity questions but it doesn't work properly

```
 public Transform plane;
 public GameObject spawnablePrefab;
 
 // Plane Properties
 float x_dim;
 float z_dim;
 
 void Start () {
     // Get the length and width of the plane
     x_dim = plane.size.x;
     z_dim = plane.size.z;
 }
 
 void Spawn () {
     // Spawn the object as a child of the plane. This will solve any rotation issues
     GameObject obj = Instantiate (spawnablePrefab, Vector3.zero, Qauternion.Identity, plane) as GameObject;
 
     /* Move the object to where you want withing in the dimensions of the plane */
     // random the x and z position between bounds
     var x_rand =  Random.Range(-x_dim, x_dim);
     var z_rand =  Random.Range(-z_dim, z_dim);
 
     // Random the y position from the smallest bewteen x and z
     var z_rand = x_rand > z_rand ? Random.Range(0, z_rand) : Random.Range(0, x_rand); 
 
     // Now move the object
     // Since the object is a child of the plane it will automatically handle rotational offset
     obj.transform.position = new Vector3 (x_rand, y_rand, z_rand);
 
     // Now unassign the parent
     obj.parent = null;
 }
```

There are only like 3 codes on the internet and non works, they are all broken in some way...
Is There a way to spawn prefabs, randomly in a given area?

Comment: In what way does this code not do what you want to happen? How is it broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

   public class RandomSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform plane;
    public GameObject spawnablePrefab;

    // Plane Properties
    float x_dim;
    float z_dim;

    void Start()
    {
        // Get the length and width of the plane
        x_dim = plane.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.size.x;
        z_dim = plane.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.size.z;
        x_dim /= 2;
        z_dim /= 2;      
         
    }

        public void Spawn()
    {
        // Spawn the object as a child of the plane. This will solve any rotation issues
        GameObject obj = Instantiate(spawnablePrefab, Vector3.zero, 
         Quaternion.identity, plane) as GameObject;

        /* Move the object to where you want withing in the dimensions of the plane */
        // random the x and z position between bounds
        var x_rand = Random.Range(-x_dim, x_dim);
        var z_rand = Random.Range(-z_dim, z_dim);

        // Random the y position from the smallest bewteen x and z
        z_rand = x_rand > z_rand ? Random.Range(0, z_rand) : Random.Range(0, x_rand);

        // Now move the object
        // Since the object is a child of the plane it will automatically handle rotational offset
        obj.transform.position = new Vector3(x_rand,0, z_rand);

        // Now unassign the parent
        obj.transform.parent = null;
    }
}
```

I have solved several errors
and changed:
x_dim = plane.size.x;
**to this**
x_dim = plane.GetComponent().bounds.size.x;

and also added
x_dim /= 2;
z_dim /= 2;

For example if the length of the plane  is 10 we need half of that(10/2=5)
Now we can write:
var x_rand = Random.Range(-x_dim, x_dim);
Ex:(-5,5)

Now it is working. You just need to call the spawn method.

Comment: on the spawn function I added the position of the plane so that the spawned items appear correctly inside the plane limits: `obj.transform.position = new Vector3(x_rand,0, z_rand) + plane.transform.position;`